# how to generate both accessKey,secretKey for aws account that has credntials for specific service(sqs), but not of specific user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

i'm creating a microservice that fetching messages from aws-sqs.
for it's connection i provide it both accessKey,secretKey of my aws account

my question is how i can generates those keys that are not related to my user so in development, other developers can use it also

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate user within IAM. This user can now be granted access only to those objects/queues you want the user to see/use.

Since every user has its own credentials, you can forward the access key and secret of this user to other developers without giving up your privileged account.

[Overview of Identity Management: Users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_identity-management.html)